# Angular 9 - Error con *ngFor y *ngIf (me funcionaba hasta Angular 7)

Tags: html5, angular9

Estoy migrando una app realizada en Angular 7 a Angular 9. En la app original, tenia varios componentes reutilizables en un directorio (shared-componentes). Estos componentes básicamente son ventanas modales que muestran información de forma dinamica, a los cuales les paso un objeto y ellos muestran informacion. Obviamente este componente utiliza ngFor y ngIf, lo cual al migrarlo a version 9 de angular no me funciona. Compila y al momento de utilizarlo no muestra info y en el inspect del browser me indica "Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'."

Mi componente es el siguiente:

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
    ChangeDetectionStrategy,
    Component
  } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'ngx-clarification',
    template:  `<div>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <span>{{ modalHeader }}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body container-comments">
        <div class="container">
            <div *ngIf="modalObject">
                <div *ngFor="let item of modalObject">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="media comment-box">
                            <div class="media-left">
                                <i class="btn-outline-claro far fa-comment-alt fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <p>{{item.datetimeclarif}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading">{{item.name}}</h4>
                                <p>{{item.clarification}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="modalObject.length === 0">
                No hay comentarios para el trámite.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-primary" (click)="closeModal()">Cerrar</button>
    </div>
</div>`,
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
styleUrls: ['../../app.component.scss', './clarification.component.scss'],
})
export class ClarificationComponent implements OnInit {
    modalHeader: string;
    modalObject: any;

    constructor(private activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
) {}

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    closeModal(): void {
    this.activeModal.dismiss();
    }
}
```

y lo utilizo de la siguiente forma desde otro componente llamado home.componente.ts:

```
import { ClarificationComponent } from '../../shared-components/clarification/clarification.component';
...
onViewClarifications(managementid) {
  this.manService.GetClarifications(managementid).subscribe(
    data => {
      if (data['body']['clarifications']) {
        const activeModal = this.modalService.open(
          ClarificationComponent, { size: 'lg',
                                  container: 'nb-layout',
                                  backdrop: 'static' });
        activeModal.componentInstance.modalHeader = 'Observaciones del trámite #' + managementid;
        activeModal.componentInstance.modalObject = data['body']['clarifications'];
        activeModal.result.then(() => {
        }, (reason) => {
        });
      }
    },
    error => {
      const eh: ErrorHandle = new ErrorHandle(this.router, this.errorService);
      eh.handleError(error);
    },
  );
}
```

Pero como les comenté mas arriba, el modal se abre normalmente pero no muestra informacion porque me indica que ngIf y ngFor no son propiedades conocidas de div.
A alguien se le ocurre que puede estar pasando? GRACIAS de antemano!

Comment: Generalmente esto sucede si no tienes importado en tu módulo la dependencia (en `imports`) CommonModule

Comment: @PabloLozano es que justamente mi componente no tiene un .module.ts...mi componente consta solamente del .component.ts y así funcionaba en angular 7. Yo puedo definir un componente reutilizable creandolé un .module.ts ??

Comment: pregunto porque todos los ejemplos de componentes "reutilizables" modales que encontré no lo incluyen

Comment: Cuando creas una aplicación o una librería, los componentes tienen que ser parte de un módulo